# Derivative of eigenvalues w.r.t. a tensor

Tags: eigenvalues, tensor

$E$ is a real, positive-definitive 3x3 symmetric tensor (I am thinking about the strain tensor in solid mechanics). We perform eigendecomposition and get:

$$E_p=\sum_{i=1}^{3}λ_iN_i⊗N_i$$

into its principal components, where $λ_i$ are its eigenvalues and $N_i$ are its eigenvectors.
My question is, is there a closed form solution for $\frac{∂λ_i}{∂E}$
?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p(\lambda)$ be the characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)=\det(E-\lambda I)$. Then $p(\lambda)=(\lambda_1(E)-\lambda)(\lambda_2(E)-\lambda)(\lambda_3(E)-\lambda)$. Differentiate in $E$ and then set $\lambda=\lambda_i(E)$: 
$$
\frac{\partial \lambda_i}{\partial E}
=
\frac{1}{(\lambda_j-\lambda_i)(\lambda_k-\lambda_i)} \left.\frac{\partial \det(E-\lambda I)}{\partial E}\right|_{\lambda=\lambda_i(E)}
$$
if $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\}=\{\lambda_i,\lambda_j,\lambda_k\}$.

Comment: I am not sure if that is closed form enough.

Comment: Thank you very much, is there any references for this formula?

Comment: I don't know a reference. It is sometimes used as an example of applying the implicit function theorem in several variable calculus; it proves that, on the open set of square matrices all of whose eigenvalues arel distinct, the eigenvalues are analytic functions of the matrix entries.

Comment: Doing the calculation I find a difference in the sign of the term $\frac{1}{(\lambda_i-\lambda_j)(\lambda_i-\lambda_k)}$ but i do not understand the reason.Regarding the term $\frac{\partial det(E-\lambda I)}{\partial E}$ which equation can I use. I know how to calculate $\frac{\partial det(E)}{\partial E}$ but in this case it is different.

Comment: You might find a reference in Kato, *Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators.*

Comment: I solved the problem on the sign but I would like to ask you if this formulation for $\frac{\partial det(E-\lambda I)}{\partial E}\Bigg\rvert_{\lambda=\lambda_1}$  is correct. Since I can express $p(\lambda)$ also as: $$p(\lambda)=\lambda^3-I_1\lambda^2+I_2\lambda-I_3$$ where $I_1$ $I_2$ $I_3$ are the invariants of $E$ is it correct this equation?  $$\frac{\partial det(E-\lambda I)}{\partial E}\Bigg\rvert_{\lambda=\lambda_1}=-\frac{\partial I_1}{\partial E}\lambda^2\Bigg\rvert_{\lambda=\lambda_1}+\frac{\partial I_2}{\partial E}\lambda\rvert_{\lambda=\lambda_1}-\frac{\partial I_3}{\partial E}$$

Comment: Correct, but you can also now plug in $\lambda=\lambda_1$ directly where you have $\lambda^2$ in the first term and $\lambda$ in the second term. Careful with signs: usually the signs are set so that $I_3=\det E$, and you have the opposite.

Comment: In my convention $I_3=detE$, why do say that I have the opposite?

Comment: I fixed the signs in my calculation above.

Comment: If you plug in $\lambda=0$ you should get $p(\lambda)=\det(E)$, if you define $p(\lambda)=\det(E-\lambda I)$. But then $p(\lambda)=\det(E)-\lambda(\lambda_1\lambda_2+\lambda_1\lambda_3+\lambda_2\lambda_3)+\operatorname{tr}(E)\lambda^2-\lambda^3$. There are clearly two different sign conventions for the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Now everything seems to be fine. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is way better using the formula
$$\frac{\partial\lambda_i}{\partial E}\cdot F=\frac{N_i^TFN_i}{N_i^TN_i}\,.$$
Just a comment tfollowing Kato's book). The differential $\frac{\partial\lambda_i}{\partial E}$ might not exist, when $\lambda_i$ has multiplicity $\ge2$. Nevertheless, if the symmetric tensor $E$ depends analytically upon **one** parameter (that is $s\mapsto E(s)$ is analytic over an interval $J$), then $s\mapsto\lambda(s)$ can be determined analytically.